# Contents overflowing during page refresh

Tags: html

Here's what I'm dealing with - http://fitty-bitty-body.tumblr.com/
My contents seem to overflow on page refresh. This theme was 'tweaked' for me in a 2 column theme just recently and that's when the problems started.
Help please? I have no idea what I'm dealing with here..

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove unnecessary elements and combine floating divs into a single div with a table.

Comment: how do I know what's unnecessary? Sorry, I only know the basics of html/css :(

Comment: Unnecessary elements are redundant animation and other jewelry.